# Order alphanumerical list in PHP

Tags: php, alphanumeric

HI,
i need to order a list in PHP that looks like:
B1200
120A81
00A12
00A22
C100B
C100C

ordered list would be:
00A12
00A22
120A81
B1200
C100B
C100C

I was thinking about splitting each line in multidimensional arrays and order it but i am stuck and maybe theres a completely different way for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If the normal sort function will do what you want then splitting/sorting it would be easy:

```
// break up the string into an array on spaces
$new_array = explode(' ', $input);
// sort the array
sort($new_array);
// put the string back together
$sorted_string = implode(' ', $new_array);
```

or, more succinctly:

```
$sorted_string = implode(' ', sort(explode(' ', $input)));
```

If the default `sort()` won't give you what you want you should check out [the usort() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: I'd like to add, that you may even use the "natsort" function.

Comment: Use sort with the SORT_NUMERIC flag: sort($new_array, SORT_NUMERIC);

#  SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
# SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
# SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
# SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings

Comment: SORT_NUMERIC is wrong in this case (not all digits, also letters). SORT_STRING is the correct one. If the hex strings can be mixed case you want to convert them to all upper or all lower before sorting (maybe even splitting)